# try/catch not working with PHP PDO

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have the following bit of code:

```
try {
  $sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO provider_specialties (id,specialtyID) VALUES (?,?)");
  $sth->execute(array($provID,$specialtyID));
}
catch(PDOExecption $e) { echo "PDO Error: ".$e->getMessage(); exit; }
```

When ok data is being inserted, it works fine.  But when it's fed data that would cause a foreign key exception, instead of catching the exception, it crashes the script with a fatal error.  I do have the

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
```

set to make sure it throws exceptions.  I've seen a few others post about similar try/catch issues here, but none matching this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the same problem by fixing Exception ortograph :

replace `PDOExecption` by `PDOException`

Comment: Holy crap... you wouldn't believe how long I worked on this problem.  Thank you.  *sigh*

Comment: your IDE should really notify you of this, misspelling. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have the `use PDOException;` statement for that exception, get it from the global namespace:

```
try {
  $sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO provider_specialties (id,specialtyID) VALUES (?,?)");
  $sth->execute(array($provID,$specialtyID));
}
catch(\PDOException $e) { echo "PDO Error: ".$e->getMessage(); exit; }
```

Also, you have a typo (not sure if here in the question only or also in your code, `PDOExecption` should be `PDOException`)